# Aggregate time series object by month R

Tags: r

I have a time series object in R like this

```
anom_tsUNAD <-  ts(data, start=c(1922,1), frequency=12)
```

and I would like to plot the mean value for each month without converting it to a data frame. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `monthplot(anom_tsUNAD)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could get the `mean` for each 'month' using `tapply` and then `plot`

```
 meanVal <- tapply(anom_tsUNAD, cycle(anom_tsUNAD), FUN=mean)
 plot(meanVal)
```

The `cycle` gives the numeric position in the cycle for each observation.  For 'Jan' it is 1 and 'Dec' it is 12.  We use that as a grouping variable in the `tapply` to calculate the `mean`.

#### data

```
 anom_tsUNAD <- ts(1:40, start=c(1922,1), frequency=12)
```

Comment: It seems to work, never heard of `cycle` before. it's like `col` in `data.frame`s it seems.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind loading another package, I recommend using the aggregate function in **zoo** or similar functions in **xts**. You will probably need these packages anyway, especially if you run into ragged timeseries data. Here are examples of aggregating to a monthly timeseries using **[zoo](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/aggregate.zoo)** followed by **[xts](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xts/docs/apply.monthly)**:

**zoo:**
    monthlyTS <- aggregate(dailyTS, as.yearmon, sum)

**xts:**
    monthlyTS <- apply.monthly(xts(dailyTS), mean)

Pure syntactic sugar! What's really nice about **xts** is that you can aggregate by week. However, it's trivial to add new aggregation functions to the **zoo** function too.

Cheers,

Adam