# time series aggregation by month in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

In mydataset, the dates in day format. i need aggregate it in to month format.
to make it clear, here mydataset.

```
mydat
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("12.01.2015", "13.01.2015", 
"14.01.2015", "15.01.2015"), class = "factor"), Y = c(200L, 50L, 
100L, 50L, 200L, 200L, 50L, 200L, 100L, 1000L, 1000L, 50L, 50L, 
100L, 200L)), .Names = c("date", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Aggreation must by sum of Y.
in output i expect this format
01.2015 3550(the sum of Y variable for jan,2015)
02.2015 4000(the sum of Y variable for feb,2015)

How to do it?
i tried do it like here [Aggregate time series object by month R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917181/aggregate-time-series-object-by-month-r) , but it didn't help me.
How do it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution using `aggregate`:

```
with(mydat, aggregate(
    Y, 
    list(month_year = format(as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d.%m.%Y"), "%m/%Y")), 
    sum))
#  month_year    x
#1    01/2015 3550
```

Explanation: Extract `month_year` component from `date` and sum `Y` by `month_year` using `aggregate`.

---

### Sample data

```
mydat <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("12.01.2015", "13.01.2015",
        "14.01.2015", "15.01.2015"), class = "factor"), Y = c(200L, 50L,
        100L, 50L, 200L, 200L, 50L, 200L, 100L, 1000L, 1000L, 50L, 50L,
        100L, 200L)), .Names = c("date", "Y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
        -15L))
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful too:)

Answer (score 1):

We create a grouping variable with year + month and then do the `sum`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
mydat %>%
   group_by(yearMon = as.yearmon(dmy(date))) %>% 
   summarise(Y = sum(Y))
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and useful answer

Answer (score 1):

**1) data.frame** Use `aggregate` and a `"yearmon"` class grouping variable:

```
library(zoo)

fmt <- "%d.%m.%Y"
aggregate(mydat["Y"], list(Date = as.yearmon(mydat$date, fmt)), sum)

##       Date    Y
## 1 Jan 2015 3550
```

**2) zoo** You might consider using a time series representation rather than a data frame.   This makes many time series operations easier.  Here we use `read.zoo` to convert `mydat` to a zoo object. `fmt` is from above.

```
library(zoo)

Y <- read.zoo(mydat, FUN = as.yearmon, format = fmt, aggregate = sum)
```

giving this zoo object:

```
Y
## Jan 2015 
##     3550
```

Although unnecessary, if you want to convert it back to data frame see `?fortify.zoo` .

**3) xts/zoo**

Convert to an xts time series representation `x` and then use `aggregate.zoo` creating a zoo object `z`.  `fmt` is from above.

```
library(xts)  # also pulls in zoo

x <- xts(mydat["Y"], as.Date(mydat$date, fmt))
z <- aggregate(x, as.yearmon, sum)
z
## 
## Jan 2015 3550
```